# React.js: npm start shows a different default route

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend

I'm new to react and I have a weird problem that every time I do npm start, I get on the same
page! how do I change it? (tried with few projects! the same page!)

**routing:**

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Page404 } from "./Page404";
import { Login } from "./Login";
import { Logout } from "./Logout";
import { Register } from "./Register";

export const Routing = () => {
return (
<div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />

    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
    <Route component={Page404} />
  </Switch>
</div>
);
};
```

and the default route that I always get is:
http://localhost:3000/login-auth
EVERY time after npm start.

btw that started to happen when I installed firebase.
in this project I'm not even using firebase and it keeps happening

Thanks!

**first edit**
I've noticed that I didn't mention important parts:
first: I don't have a home component yet (wanted to practice log in pages)
second: the app component: which contain the router {i needed the router that way because the header using it as well}

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routing } from "./Components/Routing";
import "notyf/notyf.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuBar } from "./Components/MenuBar/MenuBar.jsx";

function App() {
return (
 <div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <header>
      <MenuBar />
    </header>
    <body>
      <Routing />
    </body>
  </BrowserRouter>
 </div>
 );
}
```

I've tried to uninstall firebase (although I'm not using it in this project)
and it did not work as well

** I SOLVED IT! **
I had a "homepage" setting in my package.json that lead me there for some reason

Comment: Are these all the routes you have or only the auth ones? I expect there is an auth middleware somewhere that re-routes from `/` to `/login-auth` at app mount.

Comment: @SultanH. thanks for the response!
i dont have any middleware, but how do i check ?

Comment: I suggest looking for all implementations of `history.push` `history.replace` or router's `Redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, first of all why didnt you rap up your `<Switch></Switch>` in `<Router/>` tag?

Mostly the router file structure is like this

```
    import React from "react";
    import {
     BrowserRouter as Router,
     Switch,
     Route,
     Link
    } from "react-router-dom";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

        
           <Switch>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
               <Users />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

   function Home() {
     return <h2>Home</h2>;
   }

   function About() {
     return <h2>About</h2>;
   }

   function Users() {
     return <h2>Users</h2>;
   }
```

Comment: it's the same, and the routing file looks very readable with a switch statement

Comment: where is the <Router/> then? wait switch statement? you mean switch tag right? I'm asking why didn't you do  `<Router><Switch></Switch></Router>` ? Otherwise routing won't work

Comment: I've just edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `http://localhost:3000/login-auth`, you want to see `http://localhost:3000`. If that's the problem:

1. It goes to login page because you have `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />`
2. Even if you delete this line, you will still face problems, because I cannot see your home component. Where is it?
3. And also you need to wrap your routing with `<Router>` and `<Switch>` tags as ASWIN CHANDRON noted.
4. Also, I kindly advise you to update your knowledge to new React syntax. And to use `exact` keyword. So, instead of `<Route path="/login" component={Login} />` use `<Route exact path="/login"><Login /></Route>`

And also instead of `import { Login } from "./Login";` you can type `import Login from "./Login";`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Abdulhakim 
Yes this is the problem I'm facing, and instead of just "login"
it takes me to "login-auth"

I've updated my answer with the router location and added the exact keyword and its still not working =\ all started when i installed firebase for some reason

Comment: I see you found solution by yourself. You can write your solution as an answer to this post, and tag it as answer. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, the problem was in the package.json, i had "homepage" option and it just throw me there after npm start